# enable submit button using Jquery if any form element is clicked

Tags: jquery, django, forms, event-handling, django-templates

I'm using a django template and jquery to create a form. I want the submit button to be disabled unless a user clicks any of the form elements. I tried a simple one-liner that I thought would work, but it doesn't. I also tried attaching the handler to the class "q1_input" and I've tried .focus and .click, but nothing is enabling the button.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#autofillbox1" ).autocomplete( {"source": {{ choices1|safe }}});
        $( "#autofillbox2" ).autocomplete( {"source": {{ choices2|safe }}});
        $("#brainytop").append($("#heading"));
        $('#q1_form').children().change(function(){$("#q1_submit").removeAttr('disabled');});
    });

</script>
<div id="content">
    {% if show_q1 %}<div class="left">
        <p class="title"><strong>{{ q1.title }}</strong></p>
        <form id="q1_form" action="{{ next }}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if q1.answer_type == "longtext" %}
            <textarea class="q1_input" name="r{{ ref1 }}" rows="6" cols="36"></textarea>
        {% else %}{% if q1.answer_type == "slider" %}
            <div id="slider1" style="padding-top:1.5em;padding-right: 1em;padding-left:.5em;overflow: visible;">
            {% for r in q1.responseoption_set.all %}
                <div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:40px;padding-left:10px;">
                <label>{{ r.text }}</label>
                <select class="q1_input" name="r{{ r.id }}" id="slider{{ r.id }}">
            {% for v in range1 %}
                <option value={{ v }}>{{ v }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select><script>$('#slider{{ r.id }}').selectToUISlider({tooltip: false, labels: {{ labels1 }}}).hide();
                </script></div>{% endfor %}</div>
        {% else %}{% if q1.answer_type == "autofill" %}
            <input name="response" class="q1_input" id="autofillbox1" placeholder="Just start typing..."/>
        {% else %}{% if q1.answer_type == "radio" %}
            {% for r in q1.responseoption_set.all %}
                <span class="r"><input class="q1_input" type="radio" name="r" id="q1_r{{ r.id }}" value="{{ r.id }}"/>
                <label for="q1_r{{ r.id }}">{{ r.text }}</label></span><br>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            {% for r in q1.responseoption_set.all %}
                <span class="r"><input class="q1_input" type="{{ q1.answer_type }}" name="r{{ r.id }}" id="r{{ r.id }}" value="{{ r.id }}"/>
                <label {% if q1.answer_type == "text" %}class="textanswer"{% endif %}for="r{{ r.id }}">{{ r.text }}</label></span><br>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}{% endif %}{% endif %}{% endif %}
        <input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" value="{{ q1.pk }}">
        <input id="q1_submit" class = "submit" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: upon request, rendered code looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#autofillbox1" ).autocomplete( {"source": []});
        $( "#autofillbox2" ).autocomplete( {"source": []});
        $("#brainytop").append($("#heading"));
        $('#q1_form').children().change(function(){$("#q1_submit").removeAttr('disabled');});
    });

</script>


<div id="content">
    <div class="left">
        <p class="title"><strong>Do you feel comfortable walking alone on campus at night?</strong></p>
        <form id="q1_form" action="/canvas/chart/" method="POST">

        <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='a1a2fe72c2660b05341051a85351626f' /></div>


                <span class="r"><input class="q1_input" type="radio" name="r" id="q1_r295" value="295"/>
                <label for="q1_r295">Yes</label></span><br>

                <span class="r"><input class="q1_input" type="radio" name="r" id="q1_r296" value="296"/>
                <label for="q1_r296">No</label></span><br>


        <input type="hidden" id="qid" name="qid" value="126">
        <input id="q1_submit" class = "submit" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

EDIT2:

another interesting thing is that if I click, the disabled attribute is set to "", but there appear to be some custom jquery css settings that are not recognizing the change. Firebug shows:

I'm assuming "aria-disabled" (whatever that is, honestly, I don't know) and the css class are what's preventing the re-enable. Not sure why those aren't getting updated with the attribute removal, though... or how to fix that (easily, at least)

Comment: Can you show rendered code (i.e. the ode that will be delivered to the browser)? This looks like it's entirely a front-end problem, so it's usually a good idea to focus on the front-end code.

Comment: Your code is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/rCWx8/2/ - so something else is going wrong. Maybe one of the first three lines in your `.ready()` function is throwing an error?

Comment: It seems to be getting all of the way through the document.ready, but not attaching the handler correctly. I put alerts throughout the ready function, which all showed up, but another alert I put inside the .change handler did not show up... I'm not sure why. I also changed it back to using the class as a selector, which did not work either.

Comment: edit, sorry, the alert did appear. So it's seeing the focus, but just not removing the attribute...?

Answer (score 1):

See this jsfiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/6DXSa/

Functionality works perfectly, and it's basically the code you already have. There must be something else not included here that's conflicting.

**UPDATE** This jsfiddle actually uses your HTML source and still works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6DXSa/1/

Comment: The jsfiddle works because the markup is different than the OP's (the inputs are direct children of the form).

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.6 you cannot use `.removeAttr()` to successfully change certain attributes.  Its a bit confusing, but basically jQuery is separating out actual html attributes (name, id, etc.) and js object properties that can be represented as attributes (checked, disabled).  Use `.removeProp()` instead of `.removeAttr()`.

See the [jQuery docs on `.removeProp()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) for more info.

Comment: Ummm... he didn't use `attr`. He used `removeAttr`. Totally different.

Comment: Same thing applies.  He should be using `removeProp`. http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/

Comment: jQuery backed off the prop issue after much wailing and gnashing of teeth by the community. Both attr and removeAttr can be used the same as they always have been.